# Foundation 5 sticky not working

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'm using foundation 5 and I'm trying to make the menu a sticky menu.
I've tried all the options that I could find, but I'm not sure if I missed something.

Here is my nav code

```
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-options="sticky_on: large">
            <?php echo $page->mainMenu($page_id); ?>
        </nav>  
   </div>
```

If there is anything else you need to know please let me know

Comment: added all requred js files?and initialized foundation?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you are missing `data-topbar` in your `nav`.

Instead of `<nav class="top-bar" data-options="sticky_on: large">` try `<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar data-options="sticky_on: large" role="navigation">`.

I also added `role="navigation"` for accessibility reasons, assuming that this navigation is your primary navigation for your site.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/adam-huffman/full/Eoyjz) example of the sticky top-bar working. I removed the `data-options="sticky_on: large"` attribute from the example because it was not playing nicely within codepen.

If you have any questions let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure you have including the javascript file `<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>` for top bar to work.

Place to before as below -

```
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
```

Reference - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html